# Maths in function not working?

Tags: solidity

so I have a function `getPriceReserveBuySUForEth` that is returning the incorrect value and I'm not sure why :|
I guess what the function does and the purpose doesn't really matter so I won't waste the space here
The function:

```
function getPriceReserveBuySUForEth(uint256 _value) public view returns (uint256) {
    require(getAvailableReserveUSD(0) > 0);                     // Need to have some reserve available in order to buy SU back

    uint256 maxReserveAvailable = address(this).balance * getEthPrice() * percentDropBeforeBonds / 100;
    uint256 m = 2 * maxReserveAvailable / ((maxReservePriceDeviationInCents * 10**24)**2);
    uint256 amountReserveUsedUp = maxReserveAvailable - uint(getAvailableReserveUSD(0));
    uint256 averageTradePrice = sqrt(2 * (amountReserveUsedUp + _value) / m);
    uint256 tempVal = 10**26 - averageTradePrice;
    return tempVal;
}
```

When using `0` as the input, it sgould return 10^26, however it returns `0`.

`averageTradePrice` should = 0. Therefore 10^26 - 0 should = 10^26.
I tested this with a function `y`:

```
function y(uint256 _value) public view returns (uint256) {
    return 10**26 - 0;
} // I know _value doesn't do anything here - I was just lazy in copy/pasting
```

This correctly returns 10^26.
Also I created a function `x` to test that `averageTradePrice` does indeed = 0:

```
function x(uint256 _value) public view returns (uint256) {
    require(getAvailableReserveUSD(0) > 0);                     // Need to have some reserve available in order to buy SU back

    uint256 maxReserveAvailable = address(this).balance * getEthPrice() * percentDropBeforeBonds / 100;
    uint256 m = 2 * maxReserveAvailable / ((maxReservePriceDeviationInCents * 10**24)**2);
    uint256 amountReserveUsedUp = maxReserveAvailable - uint(getAvailableReserveUSD(0));
    return sqrt(2 * (amountReserveUsedUp + _value) / m);
}
```

This is the exact same function as `getPriceReserveBuySUForEth`, except it returns the value for `averageTradePrice` instead of `20^26 - averageTradePrice`. `x(0)` does indeed return 0 like it should.
So why does `getPriceReserveBuySUForEth` return 0 when it should return 10^26??

Comment: Can you give an small example we can test? The value of some variables do not appear in your question like balance or getEthPrice(). Are optimizations enabled during compilation? From the details it might be a compiler bug, or an overflow/underflow.

Comment: Thanks for you response Ismael - I managed to figure it out though :)
Turns out the issue was that `m` was a number much less than 1 (close to 0), so solidity interpreted it as 0, which messed up the rest of the calculation. Not having floats is sooooo frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was that m was a number much less than 1 (close to 0), so solidity interpreted it as 0, which messed up the rest of the calculation. Not having floats is sooooo frustrating!

Comment: Solidity will return 0 for any number between 0 and 1, not just ones "much less than 1". It uses [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) which always rounds toward zero. So even `9999/10000` will resolve to zero.